Fibrations of categories with terminal objects
Fix $\mathbf{B}$ for a category with pullbacks.

Proof: $(\Longrightarrow)$ Suppose that $P$ is a fibration of categories with terminal objects. Then for every $I$ in $\mathbf{B}$ there is an object $1_{I} \in P(I)$ such that for every $u \colon J \to I$ in $\mathbf{B}$ and $x \in P(J)$  there is a unique $f \colon x \to 1_{I}$ such that $P(f) = u$. Then $1_{I}$ is terminal in $\mathbf{X}$ , and in fact $P(1_I)$ is terminal in $\mathbf{B}$.
$(\Longleftarrow)$ Suppose that $\mathbf{X}$ has a terminal object $1_{\mathbf{X}}$ and $P(1_{\mathbf{X}})$ is terminal in $\mathbf{B}$. Then for every $J$ in $\mathbf{B}$ there is a unique arrow $u \colon J \to P(1_{\mathbf{X}})$ in  $\mathbf{B}$. Also since $1_{\mathbf{X}}$ is terminal in $\mathbf{X}$, for every object $x$ in $\mathbf{X}$, there is a unique arrow $f \colon x \to 1_{\mathbf{X}}$ in $\mathbf{X}$. From our assumption, it follows that $f$ lies over $u$. $\Box$
Is this proof precise and correct?

Your question would look much better without this AI "proof"

$I$ is an object of $B$ and $1_{I}$ is in the fiber of $P$ over $I$. I just used the notation as it is in the notes of Benabou. However the I just wrote the proof using definitions mostly, which kind of makes it trivial.

What does the notation $I\in P(I)$ mean? Presumably $P(I)$ is just an object of ${\bf B}$, so how could it have elements?

No, I understand the notation might be throwing off. $P(I)$ is the subcategory of $X$ consisting of morphisms $\alpha$ with $P(\alpha) = id_{I}$

Sorry for the reverse comment order, and ah, I see you just mean an object of the fibre category at $I$.

But now I’m confused again; how is $f:x\to1_I$ an arrow from an object to an identity arrow? Or $x$ is meant to be an arrow and $f$ is an arrow in a slice?

$1_{I}$ is what they call an "$I$-indexed family of terminal objects."

@AlecRhea I have included the photo above.

Ah, I’m just slow waking up this morning, thank you for putting up with me.

Listen. If each $1_I$ is a terminal in $\mathbf X$, they are all isomorphic, and the isomorphism $1_I\to 1_J$ must be carried by $P$ to an isomorphism $I\to J$. So all objects of $\mathbf B$ are isomorphic to each other. Is it OK?

You are absolutely correct. I didn't understand your first comment. I guess what I did was more naive.

@Siya: one of the South African categories I was thinking of is David Holgate. He was at Stellenbosch when I visited (quite a long time ago), but I see he's now at UWC. He may be too involved in adminstration, but if you can get to talk with him he's a really nice guy and cares about students.

@PaulTaylor He is also my supervisor, so I am under him at UWC, I rarely meet him because of the admin work. My other advisor is Zurab Janelidze at Stellenbosch, who is also on a sabbatical this year.

If all of the fibres in a fibration have terminal objects then they are automatically preserved by re-indexing (also called cartesian, horizontal or prone liftings) --- you don't need to state this as another requirement and the base category doesn't have to have a terminal object itself.
In this situation, you can get rid of (the notational cost of) the base category itself by embedding it in the total category, as the terminal objects of the fibres. The (utility of the) base category is recovered by collecting the terminal and product projections in the fibres as the class of display maps.
For the theory of display maps, see Chapter VIII of my book Practical Foundations of Mathematics (CUP, 1999).  Chapter IX uses them to discuss things like exponentials (dependent products), about which you have asked questions here before.

Thank you. I just stated this as it is from Benabou's notes, but I understand your point.
